# Kernel dies when model starts fitting

Tags: python, crash, kernel, scikit-learn, anaconda

I have a script taking a complete pandas dataframe and splitting it (it was preprocessed before and read again from file to spare memory), but each time it starts fitting, the kernel dies for no reason. I have no message while I set the RF parameters to verbose, and nothing works.

I tried to run the script from a command prompt but it doesn't work either. So I guess it comes from something in the package, but had no luck googling this.

I tried to upgrade package or revert these, but nothing worked.

(My platform is following:
Win64 conda3.18.2 (build1.17.0) Python 3.4.3.final.0 requests2.8.1
in Anaconda3.)

Comment: It appears it is only related to RF classifier. RF regressor works like a charm

Comment: You may ask this on scikit-learn-general@lists.sourceforge.net mailing list, maybe it's some bug.